# Откуда берется непонятный отступ у правого края макета?

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap

Использую бутстрап 3 версии. 
Появился непонятный отступ справа.
Может быть, кто-то сталкивался?

Вот скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка на [полный скриншот](http://prntscr.com/a58h8d) страницы

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, кусочек своей верстки, на котором можно воспроизвести проблему. Однако я почти уверен, что у вас внутри одного из `.container-fluid` забыт `.row`

Comment: http://hello-site.ru/share/test/

Comment: если вас устраивает мой ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимательно посмотрев верстку, я понял, что проблема не в ней.

Дело в том, что в Bootstrap с версии <kbd>3.x</kbd> по <kbd>3.1</kbd> отсутствовал класс `.container-fluid`.
Думаю, именно поэтому, `.row` со своими отрицательными маргинами раздвигает ваш сверстанный макет шире, чем вы того ожидаете. Отсюда горизонтальная полоса прокрутки и лишний отступ.

Подключите актуальную версию Bootstrap (или хотя бы версию не меньше <kbd>3.1</kbd>), чтобы использовать класс `.container-fluid` **или** добавьте следующий стиль:

```
.container-fluid {
  margin-left: auto; /* не обязательно */
  margin-right: auto; /* не обязательно */
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

чтобы исправить описанную вами проблему.

---

Вот демонстрация проблемы в версии Bootstrap с <kbd>3.x</kbd> по <kbd>3.1</kbd>:

```css
.demo {
  background-color: rgba(65, 180, 135, .3);
  margin-top: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.container-fluid {
  background-color: rgba(195, 180, 10, .3);
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="demo">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">Некий текст</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А начиная с версии <kbd>3.1</kbd> проблема отсутствует:

```css
.demo {
  background-color: rgba(65, 180, 135, .3);
  margin-top: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.container-fluid {
  background-color: rgba(195, 180, 10, .3);
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="demo">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">Некий текст</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Update:**
После присланной верстке я вижу проблему в следующем

- У картинок внутри слайда должен стоять класс `.img-responsive`. У них
  ширина больше, чем ширина обертки. Сейчас картинки растягивают макет.
- У класса `.right_top_header` с помощью `!important` вы убрали `padding` слева и справа, но используете внутри класс `.row`, который из-за отрицательного `margin` выходит за границы блока и растягивает макет.
- В слайде вы включили кнопки `next` и `previous`, но не стилизовали их. Возможно, после исправления стилей картинок они встанут на место, но обратите на них внимание в любом случае.

Comment: К сожалению дело не в этом, используется последняя актуальная версия браузера. Есть еще какие то предположения?

Comment: Нужен пример со стилями

Comment: И я говорил не о браузере а о css библиотеке Bootstrap

Comment: @Анатолий, нужно больше подробностей о верстке

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1uWDtcjWlVCWkN3M1kwODhkdzQ/view?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Вот ссылка на архив с версткой и всем остальным, гляньте пожалуйста если не трудно. Оговорился, хотел написатт последняя версия бутстрапа, а не браузера)

Comment: @Анатолий в присланной версии верстки я не наблюдаю такое поведение. какой у   вас браузер?

Comment: Эмм. Это минимум странно, хром. Думаю самой актуальной версии

Comment: Прошу прощения, ворую впше время, вот ссылка

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folder/d/0B9BDjIBXHyHsMnZ4bEdJOVFHcWM/edit

Comment: @Анатолий, я перечислил все проблемы. Если их исправить, отступ исчезнет.